# Route VM traffic through VPN, but not host traffic

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have a VPN service that I pay for, and I would like to route traffic for a (virtual box) virtual machine thorough it, but not traffic from the (linux) host.

The VPN service uses openvpn. I have a bunch of configuration files to let me connect to different servers. I can change the type of interface (tun/tap).

From what I've read, it seems that I need to create a bridge between tap0 and vboxnet0 (the host-only virtualbox interface). I tried a few solutions for this, but nothing seems to have worked. I fear some iptables foo might be necessary, but I don't even know where to start with that.

Any help or even a prod in the right direction will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using OpenVPN in [routing](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting) configuration (tun device cannot be used with bridged mode). When OpenVPN is in bridged mode it should be enough to attach tap device to your bridge in client side.

In routing mode you need to decide how you setup routing, you can use NAT for your virtual machines and then route traffic via vpn. To enable forwarding for all interfaces:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

And configure relevant iptable rules to allow forwarded traffic and enabling NAT using `MASQUERADE` target:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i vboxnet0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o vboxnet0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Finally you can use [policy routing](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html) to route all your guest traffic via vpn:

```
# name routing table as vguest
echo 100 vguest >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# use vguest routing table for traffic from 10.0.0.0/24 (guest network) 
ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/24 table vguest

# default route via openvpn gateway
ip route add default via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 table vguest

# flush route cache
ip route flush cache
```

Alternatively you could set up another guest for running openvpn or running openvpn in a separate linux [network namespace](https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/). NAT and forwarding can be done using similar steps as above.

Answer (score 1):

Install the OpenVPN client on the virtual machine.